# Name for binary operation between two sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, binary-operations

If $\mathsf{X}$ is a set, a binary operation on it is a map $*:\mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{X}\to\mathsf{X}$. Examples of these operations are addition and multiplication in a field.

The scalar multiplication in a vector space $\mathsf{V}$ over a field $\mathsf{F}$ is defined as a map $\cdot:\mathsf{F}\times\mathsf{V}\to\mathsf{V}$. This doesn't fit into the definition of a binary operation unless $\mathsf{V}=\mathsf{F}$. What is it called? Is there a term for it?

Comment: Aaah found it! It's called a left external binary operation on $\mathsf{V}$ over $\mathsf{F}$!

Comment: The answer provided below is much more common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Action" or more generally a "left-action"

Examples:

- $F$ acts on $V$
- An action of $F$ on $V$
- A group action